# How to define key values for a newcommand function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfkeys, key-value

I have many functions like this MWE, and I want to define keys for the inputs of the functions; however I did not succeed to do so.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\circleDraw}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dh{{#1}[0]}%
\draw (0,0) circle ({0.5*\dh});
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\centering
\circleDraw{40}
\end{document}
```

This is what I tried to do with the keyval package and apparently it has problems!

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
\define@key{keys}{h}{#1}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\circleDraw}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro\dh{{#1}[0]}%
\draw (0,0) circle ({0.5*\dh});
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\centering
\circleDraw{h=40}
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate to receive alternative answers in pgfkey and keyval and please note that in some of my functions, I have more than one inputs in form of: {#1}[0] to {#1}[5], {#2}[0] to {#2}[3], etc.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you meant by "I have more than one inputs in form of: {#1}[0] to {#1}[5], {#2}[0] to {#2}[3], etc."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need keyval if you have the (IMHO more powerful) pgf keys at your disposal. You can just define your own directory and store all the keys there.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
% EE/.cd serves two purposes: define a directory EE and switch to it
% h/.initial=1 just means we introduce a key "h" and assign it the 
% initial value 1
\tikzset{EE/.cd,h/.initial=1}

\newcommand{\circleDraw}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
% this says switch to the EE directory and put the argument, #1, there
% #1 can contain arbitrarily many keys (here we only have one, but in principle it can) 
\tikzset{EE/.cd,#1}
% \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/EE/h} is the value of h in the /tikz/EE/ directory 
% the non-deprecated syntax for the circle path construction is 
% \draw circle[radius=<value>];
\draw (0,0) circle [radius={0.5*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/EE/h}*1pt}];
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\centering
\circleDraw{h=40}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course,

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{EE/.cd,h/.initial=1}

\newcommand{\circleDraw}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{EE/.cd,#1}
\draw (0,0) circle [radius={0.5*{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/EE/h}}[0]*1pt}];
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\centering
\circleDraw{h=40}
\end{document}
```

also works, but at this point you have a list of only one element.

**ADDENDUM**: Here is a more complex example with more than one key.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
% EE/.cd serves two purposes: define a directory EE and switch to it
% h/.initial=1 just means we introduce a key "h" and assign it the 
% initial value 1, the other keys are analogous
\tikzset{EE/.cd,h/.initial=10,r/.initial=5,color 1/.initial=black,color 2/.initial=black,}

\newcommand{\circleDraw}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
% this says switch to the EE directory and put the argument, #1, there
% #1 can contain arbitrarily many keys 
\tikzset{EE/.cd,#1}%
% it is often more convenient to have a shortcut for \pgfkeysvalueof{...}
% (of course, this macro is *local*)
\def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/EE/##1}}%
% \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/EE/h} is the value of h in the /tikz/EE/ directory 
% the non-deprecated syntax for the circle path construction is 
% \draw circle[radius=<value>];
\draw[color=\pv{color 1}] (0,0) circle [radius={0.5*\pv{h}*1pt}];
\draw[color=\pv{color 2}] (0,0) circle [radius={0.5*\pv{r}*1pt}];
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\subsection*{Basic example}

For most of the values the initial values are taken, except for \texttt{h}.

\circleDraw{h=40}

\subsection*{Somewhat more complex example}

Now we change all values.

\circleDraw{h=50,r=20,color 1=blue,color 2=red}


\subsection*{Overriding the initial values}

Assume you want to have the circle of radius \texttt{h} always to be purple from
now on. Then you could do
\tikzset{EE/color 1=purple}

\circleDraw{h=40}~\circleDraw{h=50,r=20,color 2=red}

\dots but still the local argument ``wins''.

\circleDraw{h=50,r=20,color 1=blue,color 2=red}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me stress, though, that this only highlights a very small subset of the features of pgf keys. If you start using them, eventually you will really love more advanced keys like `/.search also`, `/.try`, `/.expanded` and many more.

Comment: Thank you. I also prefer pgf here. How does EE/.cd work? Can you give more comments and options on the pgfkey codes?

Comment: @EnthusiasticEngineer I added explanations.

Comment: Sorry, could you please add a second parameter to your second example? For instance draw a smaller circle by a second input `r` as well? I could not define multiple parameters...

Comment: @EnthusiasticEngineer I added a slightly more complex example with some text to explain it.

Comment: thank you very much and sorry I had too much questions. The topic is new for me. My learning curve is a little slow at first, but I will get better when I understand the topics and how the functions work.

Comment: @EnthusiasticEngineer You are welcome! One learns these things IMHO best by doing and trying. (And if I look at codes that I wrote some while ago I often think OMG, what have I done here, but maybe I am not the only one with this experience... ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You have a misconception there. `keyval` doesn't alter the arguments provided to some macro as `#1`, but only uses that argument. So inside the code of `\define@key` you can use the value provided to some key as `#1`, but this is *only* usable inside `\define@key`, outside of it, `#1` has still the meaning it'd have without it.

What `\define@key` does is, it creates a macro that takes one argument and you specify what that macro should do with its argument. That macro definition will later be called by `\setkeys` with the value given to the defined key as the argument.

So if you want to define a `h` key you'd have that key define some temporary macro that stores the value which was given to it, so that this value can then be used in the rest of the macro.

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{keyval}

\makeatletter
% make sure \enthusiastic@h has an initial value and exists, even if the h key
% isn't used later.
\newcommand*\enthusiastic@h{0}
\define@key{enthusiastic}{h}{\pgfmathsetmacro\enthusiastic@h{#1}}
\newcommand{\circleDraw}[1]
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \setkeys{enthusiastic}{#1}% this will parse #1 and call the key-macros
      \draw (0,0) circle ({0.5*\enthusiastic@h});
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\centering
\circleDraw{h=40}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `expkv-cs` it is possible to define a macro that takes a single key=value argument and splits this into different arguments you can then refer to with `#1` through `#9`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{expkv-cs}

\ekvcSplit\circleDraw
  {% fallback values if the keys aren't used
      h=0         % #1
     ,color=black % #2
  }
  {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[#2] (0,0) circle[radius={0.5*#1}];
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

\begin{document}
\circleDraw{h=5pt}
\circleDraw{color=red, h=10pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]