Drawing of a newcommand that does not appear
I want to draw several copies of beakers on the same line: I have therefore managed to create a new command that works very well with a single beaker.
When I want to create a second beaker next to it, it does not appear.
What is my mistake?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\becher}[6]{%#1 début en bas à gauche ; #2 fin bécher en haut à droite ; #3 remplissage bécher ; #4 opacité ; #5 couleur plaque métallique
        \draw (#1,#2) to [controls=+(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5)] (#1+2,#2);
    \draw[fill=#3, fill opacity=#4] (#1,#2-0.5) to%
        [controls=+(90:0.5) and +(90:0.5)] (#1+2,#2-0.5);
                
        %électrode
        \draw[fill=#5] (#1+0.5,#2+2) rectangle (#1+1.5,#2-1.5); 
        
        \draw (#1,#2) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (#1+2,#2);
    \draw (#1,#2) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (#1+2,#2)%
        -- (#1+2,#2-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (#1,#2-0.5) -- (#1,#2);   
                
        \draw[fill=#3, fill opacity=#4] (#1,#2-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5)%
    and +(-90:0.5) .. (#1+2,#2-0.5);
    \draw[fill=#3, fill opacity=#4] (#1,#2-0.5) .. controls +(-90:0.5)%
    and +(-90:0.5) .. (#1+2,#2-0.5)%
        -- (#1+2,#2-2) .. controls +(-90:0.5) and +(-90:0.5) .. (#1,#2-2) -- (#1,#2-0.5);
}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{copper}{cmyk}{0,0.9,0.9,0.2}
\colorlet{lightgray}{black!25}
\colorlet{darkgray}{black!75}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Draw back of vessel 1
    \becher{0}{0}{gray}{0.2}{copper}
        \becher{1}{3}{gray}{0.2}{gray}



\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}


You define \becher with six ([6]) arguments but use only five – both in its definition but more importantly also in its usage. This breaks because the first \becher will grab the next \becher as its sixth argument leaving its five argument alone (which TikZ will more or less ignore). Change [6] to [5].

With that many variables, you may want to try a key-value syntax instead, so that you don't have to count to make sure you've gotten the right number.  It ends up being a bit more complicated to create, but harder to accidentally mess up.

@Teepeemm Can you tell me more about this because I don't know anything about it?

I don't know key-value syntax very well.  Take a stroll through https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34312/107497, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/523119/107497, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/543755/107497, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/393622/107497, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/523083/107497.  But that's just me grabbing a few hits from a web search.
